# Access to private member of a class only inside a class that has an instance of that class

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, es6-class

I'm implementing a Linked List.
I have two classes `Node` and `SingleLinkedList`. Now I need to access a private member of the `Node` class from the `SingleLinkedList` class but outside I would this wasn't possible; in this way I can return a `Node` instance from `SingleLinkedList` and the users can't accede all the data structure with that Node. In Java when a class has a object of another class (composition) can do this, in C++ there are friend classes. How can I do this in Javascript?

The following is a "example toy" that I'm implementing to test my knowledges acquired so far and to see what problems come up

```
  class Node {
             next = null;
             constructor(value) {
                this.value = value;

             }
          }

          class SingleLinkedList {
             #size = 0;
             #head = null;
             #tail = null;

             // read only get accessor property
             get size() {
                return this.#size;
             }

             isEmpty() {
                return this.#size === 0;
             }

            // insert a new Node (in tail) with the desired value
         push(value) {
            const node = new Node(value);

            if (this.isEmpty()) {
               this.#head = node;
            } else {
               this.#tail.next = node;
            }

            // the following instructions are common to both the cases.
            this.#tail = node;
            this.#size++;

            // to allow multiple push call
            return this;
         }



        get(index){
        if(index<0 || index>=this.#size)
           return null;

        let current = this.#head;


        return current.value;
     }


          }

          const myLinkedList = new SingleLinkedList();
          myLinkedList.push(3).push(5);
```

For example if I make private the `next`property of the class `Node`
 I can't anymore access the variable inside my `SingleLinkedClass`. Instead if I leave the code like that and I return a `Node` instance from some function the user can accede almost all my structure using the next property. Does it exist some , possibly simple, solution in Javascript?
I want be as clear as possible. Thus here what I want do:

```
  class Node {
         next = null;
         constructor(value) {
            this.value = value;

         }
      }

      class SingleLinkedList {
         #size = 0;
         #head = null;
         #tail = null;

         // read only get accessor property
         get size() {
            return this.#size;
         }

         isEmpty() {
            return this.#size === 0;
         }


        // insert a new Node (in tail) with the desired value
     push(value) {
        const node = new Node(value);

        if (this.isEmpty()) {
           this.#head = node;
        } else {
           this.#tail.next = node;
        }

        // the following instructions are common to both the cases.
        this.#tail = node;
        this.#size++;

        // to allow multiple push call
        return this;
     }


        get(index){
        if(index<0 || index>=this.#size)
           return null;

        let current = this.#head;


        return current; //NOW RETURN A NODE
     }

      const myLinkedList = new SingleLinkedList();
      myLinkedList.push(3).push(5);

      const myNode = myLinkedList.get(0); //RETURN NODE
```

Now,in the code above, the `get()` return a node and with it you can to scan the whole list. No good. Thus I want do:

```
class Node {
         #next = null; //PRIVATE MEMBER
         constructor(value) {
            this.value = value;

         }
      }

      class SingleLinkedList {
         #size = 0;
         #head = null;
         #tail = null;

         // read only get accessor property
         get size() {
            return this.#size;
         }

         isEmpty() {
            return this.#size === 0;
         }


        // insert a new Node (in tail) with the desired value
     push(value) {
        const node = new Node(value);

        if (this.isEmpty()) {
           this.#head = node;
        } else {
           this.#tail.#next = node; //ERROR
        }

        // the following instructions are common to both the cases.
        this.#tail = node;
        this.#size++;

        // to allow multiple push call
        return this;
     }



        get(index){
        if(index<0 || index>=this.#size)
           return null;

        let current = this.#head;


        return current; //NOW RETURN A NODE
     }



      }

      const myLinkedList = new SingleLinkedList();
      myLinkedList.push(3).push(5);
      console.log(myLinkedList.toString());
      const myNode = myLinkedList.get(0); //RETURN NODE,NO MORE A PROBLEM
```

With this last version when I return a Node from `get()` isn't any more a problem because the member of class `Node` namely `#next` is private but in this way I have an error because even inside the `SingleLinkedClass` the member `#next` isn't visible.

I hope this clarify my question

Comment: Why would you return a `Node` (that's internal to a linked list) to a user?

Comment: Could you shorten these code examples a bit, to come to the point earlier and make it easier to spot the differences between your snippets?

Comment: @Bergi Return a Node from some functions simplify a lot the implementation of other functions that I have to implement (that can reuse function that return a Node).  Furthermore I shorten a bit the code

Comment: That's about returning nodes to yourself, not to the user. You could (should) make those reusable helper methods private as well.

Comment: @Bergi No because those methods are both user method and internal methods. But I would that when they are called from my class LinkedList I can access their private members(of Node class that is the type instance returned) instead when they are called from the outside (user call) no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private identifier is scoped lexically, so `#size` and such are inaccessible outside `SingleLinkedList`. But there are a couple of ways to do it.

The simplest is to make `Node` *within* `SingleLinkedList`:

```js
"use strict";
class SingleLinkedList {
    #size = 0;
    
    constructor(size) {
        this.#size = size;
    }

    static Node = class Node {
        example(list) {
            console.log(`The size of the list is ${list.#size}`);
        }
    }
}
const Node = SingleLinkedList.Node;

// The `Node` code has access to `SingleLinkedList`'s private field:
const l = new SingleLinkedList(42);
const n = new Node();
n.example(l); // "The size of the list is ${getSize(list)}"
```

Since the scoping is lexical, and all of `Node`'s code is within the scope of `SingleLinkedList`, that works just fine.

If you don't want them nested, you can get `SingleLinkedList` to provide `Node` with a function that only `Node` has access to that will let `Node` get information from a `SingleLinkedlist`'s private fields. Here's an example, see the comments:

```js
"use strict";
const {Node, SingleLinkedList} = (() => {
    // A function SingleLinkedList will fill in
    let getSize;

    // Create the class
    class SingleLinkedList {
        #size = 0;
        
        constructor(size) {
            this.#size = size;
        }

        // This is a temporary function for filling in `getSize`
        static boot() {
            getSize = list => list.#size;
        }
    }

    // Fill in `getSize`
    SingleLinkedList.boot();
    delete SingleLinkedList.boot;

    // Find the `Node` class, which uses `getSize`
    class Node {
        example(list) {
            console.log(`The size of the list is ${getSize(list)}`);
        }
    }

    // Return them; `getSize` is entirely private to the code
    // in this function, nothing else can use it
    return {Node, SingleLinkedList}
})();

// The `Node` code has access to `SingleLinkedList`'s private field:
const l = new SingleLinkedList(42);
const n = new Node();
n.example(l); // "The size of the list is ${getSize(list)}"
```

That works because the actual use of `#size` is within the scope where it exists.

The other option is to make `Node` *within* `SingleLinkedList`:

Comment: Excuse me, may be I had to write better what I wanted to get. I'm going to rephrase the problem with an example

Comment: @Umbert - As far as I can tell, the only difference between the above and your updated question is that you want to access a private member of `Node` in `SingleLinkedList` rather than the other way around. It's the exact same thing, you just swap the classes (or even do the same thing for both classes, if you want them both to have access to something private in the other).

Comment: @Yes it's true. It's enough to swap the classes. Clever solution even if the code gets a little dirty

Comment: @and with both the solutions I can't any more put the two classes in two separate modules

Comment: Yeah, to do that you'd have to expose things more widely. The privacy comes at a cost. :-)